# Set input type="datetime-local" using PHP time()

Tags: php

I was working on a project where I have to update or change the Date & Time.

As I am using PHP-MYSQL, I have no idea how can I replace the input field with already saved (previous) Date & Time.

I wrote below code but it is not working.

Let value in
**numeric_time = 1539666333**

```
<input type="datetime-local" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-dG:i', $numeric_time); ?>">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML5 datetime-local** input field requires the format to be:

- A date.
- The literal string "T".
- A time.

**Example:** **2018-12-31T23:59**

So as Per above format your input should be as follows:

```
 <input type="datetime-local" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i', $numeric_time); ?>">
```

**Tip:** You can also check your console in your devTools for seeing what is the required format for this date input, if your console is clear then your format is correct otherwise it will display warning as below then you can test the various formats, for you ablove solution is correct:

```
The specified value "2018-10-16T07:05AM" does not conform to the required format.  The format is "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm" followed by optional ":ss" or ":ss.SSS".      jquery.min.js:3
```

Comment: welcome @JohnDoe, dont forget to upvote if you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it like this.

```
    <?php 
    $numeric_time = 1539666333;
    $dateFromTime = date('Y-m-d', $numeric_time).'T'.date('H:i', $numeric_time);
    ?>

    <input type="datetime-local" value="<?php echo $dateFromTime; ?>">
```